# Create numerical-key array from existing string-key array, with a given string-key as first item

Tags: php, array, sorting, collections

I have an array of available languages for my website, with a short ISO country code as the key for each language. I need to create a new array that contains the same info, but with numerical keys and where the first item in the new array is the current language.

I have this, which works fine:

```
$allLanguages = [
    'en' => ['locale' => 'en_US', 'code' => 'en', 'displayName' => 'English'],
    'sv' => ['locale' => 'sv_SE', 'code' => 'sv', 'displayName' => 'Swedish'],
    'de' => ['locale' => 'de_DE', 'code' => 'de', 'displayName' => 'German']
];

$currentLanguage = 'sv';


// Create new numerical-ordered array with current language info as first element
$langugeList = [];
foreach( $allLanguages as $key => $value ){
    if( $key == $currentLanguage ) 
        array_unshift($langugeList, $value);
    else 
        array_push($langugeList, $value);
};
```

Result:

```
    array (
        0 =>
            array (
                'locale' => 'sv_SE',
                'code' => 'sv',
                'displayName' => 'Swedish',
            ),
        1 =>
            array (
                'locale' => 'en_US',
                'code' => 'en',
                'displayName' => 'English',
            ),
        2 =>
            array (
                'locale' => 'de_DE',
                'code' => 'de',
                'displayName' => 'German',
            ),
    )
```

Is there another, more elegant way of doing this?

I first had the idea to copy the array values and then sort them using `usort()` (keeping the original order except for the current language), but that doesn't seem like an improvement to neither performance nor "elegancy".

I just realized that one option would be

```
$langugeList = [ $allLanguages[$currentLanguage] ];
foreach( $allLanguages as $key => $value ){
    if( $key != $currentLanguage )
        $langugeList[] = $value;
};
```

Comment: I think you have answered your own question. The last example you show, is simple and easy to understand, I would stick with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has a function built in for this: [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

```
<?php

$allLanguages = [
    'en' => ['locale' => 'en_US', 'code' => 'en', 'displayName' => 'English'],
    'sv' => ['locale' => 'sv_SE', 'code' => 'sv', 'displayName' => 'Swedish'],
    'de' => ['locale' => 'de_DE', 'code' => 'de', 'displayName' => 'German']
];

var_dump(array_values($allLanguages));
```

Outputs:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["locale"]=>
    string(5) "en_US"
    ["code"]=>
    string(2) "en"
    ["displayName"]=>
    string(7) "English"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["locale"]=>
    string(5) "sv_SE"
    ["code"]=>
    string(2) "sv"
    ["displayName"]=>
    string(7) "Swedish"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["locale"]=>
    string(5) "de_DE"
    ["code"]=>
    string(2) "de"
    ["displayName"]=>
    string(6) "German"
  }
}
```

[Live Example](https://3v4l.org/1FV6R)

---

If you combine that function with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11276338/3389737), you can move the desired array element to the top of the array before removing the keys:

```
<?php

$allLanguages = [
    'en' => ['locale' => 'en_US', 'code' => 'en', 'displayName' => 'English'],
    'sv' => ['locale' => 'sv_SE', 'code' => 'sv', 'displayName' => 'Swedish'],
    'de' => ['locale' => 'de_DE', 'code' => 'de', 'displayName' => 'German']
];

$currentLanguage = 'sv';

// Move the desired language to the front of the array
$allLanguages = [$currentLanguage => $allLanguages[$currentLanguage]] + $allLanguages;

// Get a new array with just the values
$allLanguages = array_values($allLanguages);

var_dump($allLanguages);
```

[Live Example](https://3v4l.org/5eW1v)

---

As a one liner:

```
<?php

$allLanguages = array_values([$currentLanguage => $allLanguages[$currentLanguage]] + $allLanguages);
```

[Live Example](https://3v4l.org/PpsGT)

---

As a helper function:

```
<?php

function processLanguages($current, $languages) {
    return array_values([$current => $languages[$current]] + $languages);
}

$allLanguages = [
    'en' => ['locale' => 'en_US', 'code' => 'en', 'displayName' => 'English'],
    'sv' => ['locale' => 'sv_SE', 'code' => 'sv', 'displayName' => 'Swedish'],
    'de' => ['locale' => 'de_DE', 'code' => 'de', 'displayName' => 'German']
];

var_dump(processLanguages('sv', $allLanguages));
```

[Live Example](https://3v4l.org/qhf35)